# iMovie 11 starts with a black screen. How can we make this a white screen?

Tags: imovie

I want to make a movie that is a continuous loop. All images have white background.  When I make the movie with iMovie it starts and ends with a black background image.  This does not look good when the video loops.

How do we control the basic background in iMovie?

Comment: If there is an image with a white background at the start and end of the video, I don't see how it could export a black frame. (It's never done that for me! Or maybe I didn't notice it...?) What are you using to loop the video?

Comment: That is probably the answer.  Let me try it and if yes then how about you copy your comment to the answer section.....

Comment: Very cool! I wish I'd posted that as an answer instead of a comment, so you could mark it as The Answer (and I could get some points).

Comment: @BrettFromLA you can always post it as an answer now. I would up vote it! In fact, it's pretty common to create an answer from a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an image with a white background at the start and end of the video, it should never export a black frame at either end.  (I've never seen it do that, and I've used iMovie '09 to edit hundreds of videos!)

Comment: So, the answer to this question is, "You imagined that there's a problem.  There is no problem."  I don't get it.